# Generate 20 random numbers between 0-100, and then display all odd numbers and those that are greater or equal to 50

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I'm looking to create a webpage, that can generate 20 random numbers between 0-100, and then display all odd numbers,  and all numbers that are greater or equal to 50. I know you need .grep() in jQuery but I'm struggling to make the random numbers link to my other buttons. Also how do you find odd numbers through the random numbers. If possible can they stay on the same page Any suggestion or explanations will be appreciated?

```js
//display random numbers
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
      var randNum = 0;
      var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      $("#con").append(" " + randNum);
    }
  });
});

// numbers over fifty
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    var arr = []
    while (arr.length < 10) {
      var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 51) + 50;
      
      if (arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) 
        continue;
        
      arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
    }
    document.write(arr);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  color: blue;
}

p {
  color: green;
  margin: 0;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btn">Generate Random Numbers</button>
<div id="con"></div><br/>
<button type="button" id="btn1">Get Odd Numbers </button><br/><br/>
<button type="button" id="btn2">Display Numbers Above 50 </button>
```

Comment: Can't use `document.write()` after page has loaded. It wipes out the whole page. Use `html()` or `text()` to insert content into another element. Beyond that please be more specific about what is or isn't happening as expected and note any errors thrown as per [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't need jQuery for the array/random number logic. jQuery is primarily a tool for amending the DOM. To fill the arrays you need native JS methods.

Once you've generated the array of random numbers (which you can simplify using an array function), you can then use the `filter()` method to create new arrays which are a reduced set of the action in the previous button. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // generate
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    var nums = Array.from({ length: 20 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    $("#nums").data('nums', nums).html(nums.join(', '));
  });

  // odds
  $("#btn1").click(function() {  
    var nums = $('#nums').data('nums') || [];
    var odds = nums.filter(i => i % 2 == 1);
    $("#odds").data('odds', odds).html(odds.join(', '));
  });

  // > 50
  $("#btn2").click(function() {  
    var odds = $('#odds').data('odds') || [];
    var overs = odds.filter(i => i > 50);
    $("#overs").html(overs.join(', '));
  });
});
```

```css
div { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btn">Generate Random Numbers</button>
<div id="nums"></div><br/>

<button type="button" id="btn1">Get Odd Numbers </button><br/>
<div id="odds"></div><br/>

<button type="button" id="btn2">Display Numbers Above 50 </button><br/>
<div id="overs"></div><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more explicit version of Rory's answer that doesn't use jQuery.

```js
window.generatedNumbers = [];
var output = document.querySelector('.output');

// Generates a new set of numbers
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
 window.generatedNumbers = [];
 for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      window.generatedNumbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
      
  output.innerText = window.generatedNumbers.join(', ');
});

// Shows the generated numbers that are odd
document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click', function() {
 output.innerText = window.generatedNumbers.filter(function(i) {
   return i % 2 !== 0;
  }).join(', ');
});

// Shows the generated numbers that are greater than or equal to 50
document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click', function() {
 output.innerText = window.generatedNumbers.filter(function(i) {
   return i >= 50;
  }).join(', ');
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Generate Random Numbers</button>
<button type="button" id="btn1">Get Odd Numbers </button><br/><br/>
<button type="button" id="btn2">Display Numbers Above 50 </button>

<div class="output">

</div>
```